Awaiting a promise that I constructed exits code with no errors
I verified in the console that coordinator.setupPromise is a Promise, but when I run await coordinator.setupPromise , the code never gets to the print statement after the await and instead of waiting it just exits immediately. Example console output:
$ tsx main.ts 
setup 
await setup Promise { <pending> }

Heres my code:
import { ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams, spawn } from "child_process";
import { getPortFree, sleep } from "../utils";
import 'child_process'
import fetch, { RequestInit } from "node-fetch";
import { SocksProxyAgent } from "socks-proxy-agent";

class TorInstance {

    socksPort: number;
    controlPort: number;
    dataDir: string = `./datadirs/${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}`;

    torProcess: ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams;
    agent;
    setupRes;
    setupPromise = new Promise(res => { this.setupRes = res });

    constructor(socksPort?, controlPort?) {
        this.setup();
    }

    private async setup(socksPort?, controlPort?) {
        let port1 = await getPortFree();
        let port2 = await getPortFree();

        this.socksPort = socksPort ?? port1.port
        this.controlPort = controlPort ?? port2.port

        port1.server.close();
        port2.server.close();

        // tor --SocksPort 11111 --ControlPort 11112 --DataDirectory test1
        this.torProcess = spawn(`tor`, ['--SocksPort', this.socksPort, '--ControlPort', this.controlPort, '--DataDirectory', this.dataDir].map(String));
        this.torProcess.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
        this.torProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            if (data.toString().includes(`[notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done`)) { this.setupRes() }
        })
        this.agent = new SocksProxyAgent(`socks5h://127.0.0.1:${this.socksPort}`);
    }

    public fetch(url: string, options?: RequestInit) {
        return fetch(url, {
            ...options,
            agent: this.agent
        })
    }

    public dispose() {
        this.torProcess.kill();
    }


}

class TorCoordinator {
    instances: TorInstance[] = [];
    currentIndex = 0;
    setupRes;
    setupPromise = new Promise(res => { this.setupRes = res; })

    constructor(num: number) {
        this.createInstances(num);
    }

    fetch(url: string, options?: RequestInit) {
        return this.instances[this.currentIndex++].fetch(url, options);
    }

    createInstances(num) {
        let newInstances: TorInstance[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            let newInstance = new TorInstance();
            newInstances.push(newInstance);
            newInstance.setupPromise.then(() => {
                console.log('setup!!')
                this.instances.push(newInstance)
                this.setupRes();
            })
            // todo  monitor console output for [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done, and only add to main list then
        }
    }

}


async function test() {
    console.log('setup')
    let coordinator = new TorCoordinator(10);
    console.log('await setup',coordinator.setupPromise)

    await coordinator.setupPromise;
    console.log('done await')

    coordinator.fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json').then(res => res.text().then(console.log))
    coordinator.fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json').then(res => res.text().then(console.log))
    await sleep(10000)
}
test();

And utils.ts is:
import { SocksProxyAgent } from "socks-proxy-agent"

export function sleep(m) { return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m)) }
export const torAgent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050');


import { Readable } from 'stream';

export async function streamToBuffer(stream) {
    const chunks = [];

    for await (const chunk of stream) {
        chunks.push(chunk); // Collect each Uint8Array chunk
    }

    // Concatenate all chunks into a single Buffer
    const totalLength = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => acc + chunk.length, 0);
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(totalLength);
    let position = 0;

    for (const chunk of chunks) {
        buffer.set(chunk, position);
        position += chunk.length;
    }

    return buffer;
}


export async function streamToString(stream: ReadableStream) {
    const reader = stream.getReader()
    let html = ''
    while (true) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read()
        if (value) {
            html += new TextDecoder().decode(value)
        }
        if (done) {
            return html
        }
    }
}

export async function streamToStringOld(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array<ArrayBufferLike>>) {
    const chunks: any = [];

    // Use async iteration to read from the stream
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
        chunks.push(chunk);  // Collect each Uint8Array chunk
    }

    // Concatenate all chunks into a single Uint8Array
    const totalLength = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => acc + chunk.length, 0);
    const resultArray = new Uint8Array(totalLength);

    let position = 0;
    for (const chunk of chunks) {
        resultArray.set(chunk, position);
        position += chunk.length;
    }

    // Convert the Uint8Array to a string
    return new TextDecoder().decode(resultArray);
}

import net from "net"

export async function getPortFree():Promise<{port:number,server:net.Server}> {
    return new Promise( res => {
        const srv = net.createServer();
        srv.listen(0, () => {
            // @ts-ignore
            const port = srv.address().port
            res({port,server:srv});
            
        });
    })
}

I tried awaiting a promise that I had constructed earlier, but instead of awaiting for passing to the next line, the code just exists with no error thrown.

Are you sure it is EXITING and not just the promise never being resolved?

getPortFree is a bit strange - you're opening a server, so the returned port won't be free any more?

Your TorInstance code is not handling errors well. Also I would recommend to refactor that setup method and setupPromise and setupRes into a static factory method. Then consider forwarding torProcess.stderr to the output, and installing handlers for the error and exit events.

For one thing, TorInstance never resolves the setupPromise - not 100% sure why this causes the observed behaviour (which is why I am writing a comment not an answer). If you do call this.setupRes in TorInstance your code seems to work - however the TorCoordinator promise resolves as soon as the first TorInstance resolves, which may not be what you intended.

@JaromandaX The promise is supposed to be resolved in the data handler

Oh @Bergi , I didn't see that ... I don't scroll right :D ... mustn't be called then

Your main file doesn't await the test() function. So when you call test(), it can just exit when it's done calling that function.
You should try this instead
(async () => {
    await test();
})().catch(console.error);


No, that does not make a difference. (Your code is equivalent to a simpler test().catch(console.error);)

Thanks. I learned something
